# Compute the matrix $A^n$, $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Compute $A^n$, $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$., where $
A=\left[\begin{array}{rr}
2&4\\3&13
\end{array}\right]$.

Hi guys, this is the question, I compute the diagonal matrix of $A$ and obtained this $
D=\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1&0\\0&14
\end{array}\right]$. I need use this result $(M^{-1}BM)^n$ $=$ $M^{-1}B^nM$ to find $A^n$ and I know how to use, but my problem is compute this matrix $M$ how can I compute $M$?

Comment: When you diagonalized it, you should've computed eigenvectors as well. Those are the columns and rows of $M$.

Comment: The matrix $M$ is related to the eigenvectors of the original matrix A. Suppose that $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.  Then $Av_1 = \lambda_1 v_1$ and $Av_2=\lambda_2 v_2$ where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are the corresponding eigenvectors.  Then 
$AV = VD$ where $V$ is a matrix as $V = (v_1\;v_2)$ and $D$ is your diagonal matrix of the corresponding eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

The columns of $M$ are the eigenvectors respectively of eigenvalue 1 and 14. The first one belongs to $ker(A-I)=ker \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \\3 & 12\end{pmatrix}$. You can choose $\begin{pmatrix} -4 \\1\end{pmatrix}$. The other belongs to $ker(A-14I)=ker \begin{pmatrix} -12 & 4 \\3 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, you can choose $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\3\end{pmatrix}$. Then: 
$$M=\begin{pmatrix} -4 & 1 \\1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

If a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, then what that means is there exists a decomposition of the vector space into eigenspaces. Then the form $A = MDM^{-1}$ is merely a change-of-basis from the basis in which $A$ was expressed into this new eigenbasis.

**Therefore, the entries of $M$ will be the eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalues.**

$\lambda = 1$: The corresponding eigenspace is the nullspace of the matrix $A-1 I = A-I$. So,
$$
A-I=\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1&4\\3&12
\end{array}\right]$$

then row reduce to find a single generator of this nullspace.

$\lambda = 13$: Same thing as above.

Now take the two eigenvectors found in the two cases above and form the $2 \times 2$ matrix $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to compute $f(A)$ (where $A$ is a matrix, and in your case $f(x)=x^N$) is to use: 
\begin{equation}
f(A) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint  f(z) (z-A)^{-1} \; dz 
\end{equation}

where the contour encloses all the poles of the matrix $(z-A)^{-1}$.

Sounds complicated, but it is very straightforward.

Comment: Where does this come from? I've done complex analysis but not with matrices. Thank you

Comment: @Joanpemo: give it a try to convince yourself how great it works! I do not have the reference. In a way, it is the Cauchy residue formula, whereby you simply replace the normal argument with a matrix. Maybe some of the more experienced on stackexchange can give you an explanation (you can put up a question with this topic...)

Comment: Thank you. I'm not saying it isn't great, I just didn't see it before and it looks interesting. That's why I asked you, please, for some reference. I also don't know how to do complex integration when matrices are involved.

Comment: @Joanpemo: you basically do not need to do complex integration the hard way, just mechanically apply the Cauchy residue theorem (ie, adding terms) to each function specified in your matrix elements under the integral sign.

Comment: This is true if $f$ is analytic in a domain containing the integration contour.