# Second Order Differential Equation with Matrix

Tags: matrices

How can I find the solutions to a second-order diffeq with an $n \times n$ diagonalizable matrix as its coefficients? I know how to calculate the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the matrix $L,$ but do not know how to solve the differential equation itself.

$x'' = Lx$

Answer (score 0):

hmm.... I would give it a try like this (assume that $x=x(t)$): the general solution can be written as $x(t) = C_1 \exp{(t\sqrt{L})} + C_2 \exp{(-t\sqrt{L})}$. Question is: what is $\exp{(t\sqrt{L})}$ ? You can use eigenvalue decomposition or have a look at my comment here [Compute the matrix $A^n$, $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667948/compute-the-matrix-an-n-in-mathbbn/1667984?noredirect=1#comment3406447_1667984).

Hope this is of some help...